# Найти дубли в одной таблице и перенести их в другую

Tags: sql

Имеется 2 таблицы.

Таблица 1.

```
num                         value
порядковый номер строки     значение
```

Таблица 2.

```
num1                         value       num2
порядковый номер строки 1    значение    порядковый номер строки 2
```

Как с помощью SQL-запроса найти все дубли строк в первой таблице и занести во вторую (в `num1` заносится первый номер строки, в `value` переносится значение второго столбца из первой таблицы, а в `num2` заносится номер строки, где это значение дублируется).

Пример:

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   a
5   c

num1    value   num2
1       a       4
3       c       5
```

Таблицы находятся в базе данных *SQL*

Comment: _"с помощью запроса"_ какого запроса? html в базе данных находится? если нет, и вам нужен javascript или jquery, то замените теги у вопроса.

Comment: я тегами таблицу нарисовал, что бы наглядней было, имеется в виду, что таблица в базе данных, и данную задачу необходимо решить запросом sql

Comment: А дубли в таблице 1 по каким полям искать? И еще... что если дублей не 2 а больше? что Вы хотите сохранять во второй таблице?

Comment: используйте для этого в следующий раз нормальные инструменты, жесть )

Comment: @stepofchange  _"я тегами таблицу нарисовал"_ -- понятно, но лучше так не делать.

Comment: @cyadvert Дубли ищутся по столбцу value, если дублей больше, к примеру в строка 1, 3, 5 находится одно и то же значение value (например a), то в таблицу 2 должны добавится следующие строки: 1) 1 a 3 2) 1 a 5 3) 3 a 5

Comment: @Stack в следующий раз не буду)

Comment: речь про то как вы изобразили таблицы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы выбрать данные могу предложить такой запрос:

```
select t1.num, t1.value, t2.num
from Test t1
join Test t2 on t1.value = t2.value and t1.num < t2.num
```

[SQL fiddle пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78c97/1)

Ну, а вставку данных выполнять через [insert into select](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

Comment: То что надо! Спасибо!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста ;)