# Табличный XOR в SQL

Tags: sql, sql-merge

Есть табличная переменная и таблица.

Как оставить в переменной только те строки, которые отсутствуют в таблице (используя связывание таблиц по набору полей)?

Я использую для этого `merge`:

```
merge @re tar
using (select Hash, TypeID from Hashes) src
on tar.Hash = src.Hash and tar.TypeID = src.TypeID
when matched then
delete
;
select * from @re
```

Не уверен, что это лучший вариант.

Цель: использование интерфейса для приложения, чтобы по большой таблице в БД проверить небольшой список на присутствие в БД и для отсутствующих значений продолжить обработку в программе. (Выгружать всю таблицу совершенно не хочется)

Comment: В mssql **xor** это `^`.  В булевой алгебре **хоr** это неравенство т.е. `<>` для всех sql.

Comment: В любом случае уточните СУБД. mssql mysql oracle. Для разных по-разному. Очень похоже на **mssql**

Comment: А если `select * from @re tar left join Hashes src on tar.Hash = src.Hash and tar.TypeID = src.TypeID where src.Hash is null` ? Вообще планы выполнения надо сравнивать

Comment: Вот один из похожих ответов на so http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474976/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E ну а если хотите ускорить введите md5 по всем полям, и сравнивайте вначале по md5.

Comment: @nick_n_a, да, я подразумевал под xor здесь принцип, при котором идет выбор тех значений, которые отсутствуют и отсечение тех, которые присутствуют во втором списке. Да, это MSSQL.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512206/193999)

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за пример. У меня к сожалению нет сейчас возможности сравнить планы, т.к. сейчас только этап создания БД и интерфейсов. Таблица пока пустая. Единственное, что можно сказать сразу. Вроде бы по реализации `merge` это цикл `while` в транзакции. Так что как я понимаю он не может быть параллельным. А вот с вашим примером я вот так сходу не могу оценить будет ли он параллелиться. Экспертизы не хватает(( Хотя то что есть join, вроде как тоже говорит, что параллелироваться не будет.

Comment: @i-one, спасибо! Судя по изображению Mike прав, когда прислал код, полностью аналогичный тому, что используется в примере. Но если будет время, я постараюсь сравнить на больших объемах скорость выполнения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если переформулировать ваш вопрос - то вам нужно удалить из переменной те записи, которые есть в таблице. Довольно просто, не так ли?

```
delete 
from    tar
from    @re tar
        inner join  Hashes
                on tar.Hash = Hashes.Hash 
               and tar.TypeID = Hashes.TypeID
```

Если наоборот - нужно удалить только отсутствующие в таблице записи, то используется внешнее соединение и проверка на null.

```
delete 
from    tar
from    @re tar
        left  join  Hashes
                on tar.Hash = Hashes.Hash 
                and tar.TypeID = Hashes.TypeID
where Hashes.TypeID is null
```

Использование merge оправдано в случаях, когда вам необходимо произвести разные действия с одним набором (присутствующие записи - обновить, отстутствующие - добавить, или что-то такое).